# Getting a username from url with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I seem to find it difficult to get the username from a url with params, but works when finding IDs.

To get the id from this url: `www.foo.com/users/1/post/new`, you'd use:

```
User.find(params[:id]) # same as User.find(1)
```

I thought I could do the same, [based on the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), for: `www.foo.com/users/joe/post/new`

```
User.find_by(name: params[:name])
```

How to grab the user's name from url with params using the `find` or `find_by` method? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `User` model, override the `to_param` method like this:

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

With this code, you're overriding the ActiveRecord default behaviour, so when you link to a User, it will use the `name` for the parameter instead of `id`.

Also, I recommend you to take a look at the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem as well, using which you can achieve this goal.

Comment: Thanks. Do you also have a web link for where other methods to be overwritten?

Comment: You don't need to override other methods. Just this one.